# How to fix unity 3D raycast bullet inaccuracy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm implementing shooting mechanics into a game. Since the bullet physics are hitscan, the game shoots with raycasts. However, if you shoot above or below a target, it still registers a hit (the current hit detection only seem to care about horizontal accuracy), what is the solution? Here is the current code `RaycastHit hit; if (Physics.Raycast(bulletSpawner.transform.position, bulletSpawner.transform.forward, out hit, range)) { RecieveDamage target = hit.transform.GetComponent<RecieveDamage>(); //Recieve damage is a seperate script if (target != null) { target.TakeDamage(damage); } }`

Answer (score 0):

Code is OK. Either `bulletSpawner` is not actually following your aim or `ReceiveDamage`'s collider is bigger than you think. Look at them in the inspector when you're shooting.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even consider the possibility that the bug isn't in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because your code looks ok, for debugging purposes, I would propose for you to use Gizmos or Debug drawing functions eg:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Draws a line from start to start + dir in world coordinates.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">Point in world space where the ray should start.</param>
    /// <param name="dir">Direction and length of the ray.</param>
    /// <param name="color">Color of the drawn line.</param>
    /// <param name="duration">How long the line will be visible for (in seconds).</param>
    Debug.DrawRay(rayStart, rayDir, Color.red, float.PositiveInfinity);
```

And on hit pause the game via `Debug.Break()`

Using these methods you will pause execution in the editor and see where the raycast was shoot, and because you know that you hit this given frame, you could easily inspect which part of the collider you hit.